# structure of as much as often as possible

Tags: conjunctions, coordination

What are the structures of the following sentence:

> Read **as** much and **as** often **as** possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As...as construction. But instead of 1 adverb before "as possible", we've got 2. Imagine there are 2 sentences:

> Read as much as possible. Read as often as possible.

You can make just 1 sentence and keep it short:

> Read as much and as often as possible.

Another example:

> Do it long. Do it thoroughly. Do it **as** long and **as** thoroughly **as** possible.